# Use network namespace per thread with sytem DNS resolution

Tags: python, linux-kernel, namespaces

I would like to have single Python application to work with different network namespaces. This to my understanding can be achieved on per-thread basis via `pthread.setns(...)` as explained for example in [Can I open sockets in multiple network namespaces from my Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846059/can-i-open-sockets-in-multiple-network-namespaces-from-my-python-code)

My code uses a 3rd part library which uses internally DNS resolution through socket (e.g. `socket.gethostbyaddr()`) and I would like for these socket calls to consult different per-namespace DNS settings ideally same as `ip setns exec ...` would bind-mount `/etc/netns/namespace-name/resolv.conf`. This sohuld happen based on the namespace of the thread the socket call is invoked from.

Any idea how to achieve this? Obviously I can patch the library to not use socket but some other DNS library where I can provide the settings myself but for now I would like to keep to delegation to system DNS resolver.

Comment: To my understand namespaces are per process, not thread specific, the example that you link provides code which switches the NS for a single process, it's a sequential swap of the netns, not a concurrent/parallel/multithreaded ability.

Comment: It seems you are correct